# Automatic bikes

Tags: motorcycle, automatic-transmission

I know this is a very subjective and could be off the topic,but still i want to know why are cars with auto transmission are quite popular but motorcycles with automatic transmission are very rare to see.(though automatic scooters are quite popular).
Apart from a rider's preference is there any other technical limitation/challenges  in designing and developing a bike with auto transmission.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not maintenance or repair

Comment: it's ok.but do you have any answer?Look for question,is there any technical limitation to it?

Comment: Two points are obvious : one is weight and the second is engine braking...

Comment: This is a great topic for chatting about here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any technical reason - If the bikes sold then the manufacturers would make more of them.  Here are some big auto trans motorcycles:

Honda DN-01 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_DN-01

Honda VFR1200F DCT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_VFR1200F

Honda NC700D Integra https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_NC700D_Integra

Honda NC700SD https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_NC700_series

Yamaha FJR1300AE/AS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamaha_FJR1300

Aprilia Mana 850 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aprilia_Mana_850

Honda has developed a DCT with computer controlled clutches.
Yamaha has developed a computer controlled clutch for manual trans.
Aprilia has developed a CVT for large capacity bikes.